# Calculate Percentages on Excel Pivot Table Totals

Tags: excel, pivot-table, percentage

I have Excel source data with Phase, Team, and Early or Late.  I've created a pivot table to summarize the data like this:

```
            Team 1               |  Team 2              |
Phase       Early | Late | Total | Early | Late | Total | Grand Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Phase 1       2       3      5       0       1      1          6
Phase 2       4       5      9       2       2      4         13
Phase 3       5       6     11       1       1      2         13
Grand Total  11      14     25       3       4      7         32
```

I'd like to calculate percentages of the totals (so the total early for team 1 divided by the total for team 1--or 11/25 for 44% early, and then the total late divided by the total, or 14/25 for 56% late).

I tried using formulas below the pivot table, which worked great, but they get out of whack if the source data doesn't have records that fall in a column (so if there are no late items for Team 2, that column disappears).  Is there an easy fix or a way to keep the pivot table at a set number of rows or columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of constructing formulas separately from the pivot table you can just set the pivot table to calculate the percentages directly. That way you don't have to worry about how many columns and rows are in the pivot table. In Excel 2010 (2007 s/b the same too) go to the PivotTable Tools ribbon then options and under calculations click the dropdown Show Values As and select % of Parent Column Total.

Comment: +1.  I never realized that's what "Parent Column" means and I work with pivot tables daily.

Comment: I've tried that, but then you lose the values.  The individual counts are important to the user, and the percentages in total are also important.   I'd love to find a way to see both--I guess I could add a second pivot table that is the same but shows percentages.

Comment: I ended up adding a second pivot table below the counts and using your method to show the percentages in that table.  It works great.

Comment: @rryanp, you don't need two sets of pivot tables.  You can repeat your Values field and set one to Sum and the 2nd to % of Parent Column.  Then you just drag things around in the pivot table's Column Labels box in the dialog until the two are side-by-side.

Comment: @Doug--thanks, I had tried that and got an error about overlapping pivot tables, and I thought it was referencing overlapping the data fields, but your comment made me experiment and realize it was actually referencing an unrelated pivot table I had below it that was in the way of the other pivot table expanding with the new fields.  So I just inserted a few extra rows between them, and then it worked perfectly.